# Spark not recognizing question mark (?) as nullValue parameter when reading from a csv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using PySpark 2.3.1 with Python 3.6.6 at the moment.

I need to work with a .csv file where `?` are used as `NA`. I want to make PySpark recognize `?` as NA directly, so I can treat them consequently.

I have tried `nullValue=` argument in `spark.read.csv` for that without success, and I am not sure if it has to do with the argument being improperly used or the `?` character being a problem in those cases (I have tried both `nullValue='?'` and `nullValue='\?'`).

Having read PySpark API documentation, and tried Pandas `pd.read_csv` with `na_values=` with the same outcome, I would say it there is something with `?` that makes it not to work, but feel free to tell me if I am wrong at that.

What should I do?

The file is the adult dataset from UCI: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely caused by spaces around your `null` value. The easiest situation would be if the number of leading/trailing spaces was fixed (i.e. if it's *always* one space followed by the question mark: `" ?"`). In that case, just set `nullValue=' ?'`.

If the number of spaces is not fixed, a possible solution for this is to use the `ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace` and `ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace` flags. (Assuming you're okay with ignoring leading/trailing whitespace for all values, including non-nulls).

For example, if your file were the following:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
1, ?,a,xxx
? ,5,b,yyy
7,8,?,zzz
```

where the `?` is the `null` character, but it can have either trailing or leading spaces, you could read it as follows:

```python
df = spark.read.csv(
    "path/to/my/file",
    header=True,
    nullValue='?',
    ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace=True,
    ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace=True,
    inferSchema=True
)
```

This results in the following DataFrame:

```
df.show()
#+----+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|col4|
#+----+----+----+----+
#|   1|null|   a| xxx|
#|null|   5|   b| yyy|
#|   7|   8|null| zzz|
#+----+----+----+----+
```

As you can see, the `null` values are in the correct places.

Additionally, since we set `inferSchema=True`, the data types are also correct:

```
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- col1: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- col2: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
# |-- col4: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: That's it. The problem were those spaces, I hadn't seen ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace and ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace arguments properly before. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Thought it worked at first and after that I thought it didn't work, but it was my fault because I was using nullValue=' ?' with ignore(Leading/Trailing)WhiteSpace set to True. Your answer is perfect, thanks for your time and sorry about that.